# Responsiver Sidebar Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, sidebar

I'm quite new to jQuery and I would like to change the following code that it fits my needs:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width(); //get width automaticly
  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px") {
      $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
        "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
      });
    } else {
      if (!$(this).is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
      {
        $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
          "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
        });
      }
    }   
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3okensLj/1/

It is working quiet good but a problem appears when I'm resizing the window under 500px:

When I'm clicking onto the button (?) the menu appears. If I close the menu and enlarge the window the menu and the button has disappeared and I've got a problem. How can I avoid this?

I would like to change the code, that it adds a new class to the Menu container acording to the windows size but keeping the functinality of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I dont know how to fix your code in a better way without using js $(window).resize

add this to your js

```
 var pollSlider = $("#sidebar");
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        if (!pollSlider.hasClass("marginFixed")) {
            $("#sidebar").addClass("marginFixed");
        }
    } else {
        if (pollSlider.hasClass("marginFixed")) {
            $("#sidebar").removeClass("marginFixed");
        }
    }
})
```

and css

```
.marginFixed {
   margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

you use js change your style which is not good and have to use !important to cover this

it can work but its **bad code**

and there is another way use css do this

use transition

```
.pollSlider {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 20pt;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 450px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-right 1s ease-in;
    transition: margin-right 1s ease-in;
}

.pollSlider.slideAni {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slideAni");
 });
});
```

or use css animate with keyframe

```
    .pollSlider {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 20pt;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 450px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
      }
      .pollSlider.slideAni {
          animation-name: slideAni;
      }
  @-webkit-keyframes slideAni {
      from {
          margin-right: -450px;
      }
      to {
          margin-right: 0px;
      }
  }

  @keyframes slideAni {
      from {
          margin-right: -450px;
      }
      to {
          margin-right: 0px;
      }
  }
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("slideAni");
 });
});
```

but in this way you have to add other animate class to animate slide back, I just give you a way to try(I'm sure it will work)